# Hide Message or Fade out Alert message

Tags: jquery, smart-wizard

I want to hide the alert message when I moved to next step.

I am  using jquery smart wizard tab navigation. Please check the sample code.

```
if(step == 1){
            if(validateStep1() == false ){
              isStepValid = false; 
             $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please correct the errors in application form and click next.');

              $('#wizard').smartWizard('setError',{stepnum:step,iserror:true});         
            }else{
              $('#wizard').smartWizard('setError',{stepnum:step,iserror:false});
            }
          }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your if condition ... i can see only else part

Comment: pla edit this to your question above .. so that people can help you better

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in method:

```
if (stepnumber == 1) {
    $(function() { 
            $("#wizard").smartWizard("hideMessage");
            $("#wizard").smartWizard("fixHeight"); 
        });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just call:

```
msgBox = $('.msgBox');
msgBox.hide();
```